# Calculate sliding durations in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of Tuples and a datum like below

```
val datum =("R",89)
val dataList = Seq(("R",91),("R",95),("X",96),("S",98))
```

I want to calculate the duration between elements in the list , starting with the datum so the result would be

```
res0:> Seq(("R",7) , ("X",2))  //R - 96-89 , X - 98-96
```

Things I have tried are not functional

a) I used a sliding on the list and used a pattern match with an accumulator to hold the values. This used a Boolean and a listBuffer to keep adding values into the list

b) Used a map function with an accumulator tuple with a pattern match for the tuple , compare the _1 values and when the values change compare reset the accumulator and collect the result of the subtraction

I was imagining if foldLeft or fold functions could be used to make it more "functional". In this case we would have .foldLeft(List()) as the initial value and then write a map function that takes in 2 tuples and compare manually possibly with a flag as well.

Any pointers as to how this can be made "functional"
b) Used a map function that

Comment: what about duration from R to S ? clarify the distance logic clearly.

Comment: For S there is no end in this list. In my next slide (time based slide logic I have) S will be the datum for further calculation. In a pattern match with a sliding , this the edge case of a case(u) , that returns None. Only adjacent states need calculation. If all the tuples were of the same state , I would have none again as the states have not changed.

Comment: please see my answer below :) you should have general idea how to proceed :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do

first create a function that takes `datum`, `dataList` and `empty list` (which will be the final list). And you iterate through the function using your logic.

```
def func(x : Tuple2[String, Int], y : Seq[Tuple2[String, Int]], z: List[Tuple2[String, Int]]) : List[Tuple2[String, Int]] = y match {
  case (a::b) => if(x._1 == a._1) func(x, b, z) else func(a, b, z :+ (x._1, a._2-x._2))
  case Nil => z
}
```

Thats all now just call the function

```
val finalTuples = func(datum, dataList, List.empty[Tuple2[String, Int]])
```

`finalTuples` is `finalTuples: List[(String, Int)] = List((R,7), (X,2))`